# email arriving at wrong exchange server

Tags: exchange, subdomain, mx-record

We are having problems with receiving email from one customer, where any emails they send to subdomain.domain.com is being received by the exchange server for domain.com, resulting in an error "non-routable-subdomain" as the two exchange server are completely separate and in two different countries.

I'm pretty sure this is a problem their end as we receive thousands of emails a day and the only emails with this problem are sent from this one customer.  does anyone have any idea what could cause this?, i have got them to flush dns on their server and our MX records and server IP has not changed in the last 3 years

Comment: this is extremely difficult to troubleshoot without knowing more about your environment, the mail routing and the MX records for your domains.

Answer (score 0):

2 options as I see it:

1) This is a DNS issue on their end. Run CMD on their exchange server and try the following - nslookup -> set type=mx -> "your sub domain name". See if the result matches the actual server.

2) They have a manual send connector set up to your organization, either on the exchange server or on their mail relay, which routes all mails sent to *.parentdomain.com to their Exchange server (the wild card causing it to include your sub domain as well). If its on Exchange it can be checked under Organization Configuration -> Hub Server -> Send Connectors (assuming its Exchange 2007 / 2010).

Good luck.

Comment: You are assuming the sending party is running Exchange.  The first option (dns issue) is independent of whether they run Exchange or not and can be figured out on any win/linux system.  The 2nd option would require them to be running Exchange on the sending side, again an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the running issue where it is possible that an email once made it from that server and all replies and the contact was created from that errant email.
you can try sending a new fresh email information them to update the contact or to reply back to your email to verify that it works.
I've seen this a couple of times when i've had a backup server setup when the primary failed... all mail ended up coming from that 1 person through the backup server only.
also if they're a windows user sending the mail get them to go to cmd and ipconfig /flushdns
as that sometimes corrects it as well.